# How to find 'Attribute error' of pandas in python at jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

**This Is My Error**

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'name': ['Riya','Ashwin','Kritika'],
         
'marks': [91,81,71,61],
          
'Roll.No.':[20,1,15],
        }

df = pd.Dataframe(dict1)
```

*That is error*

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-f647dfa4ad5f> in <module>

----> 1 df = pd.Dataframe(dict1)


~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
  
  242         return _SparseArray
  
  243 

--> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
   
 245 
    
246 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

Comment: Case sensitive. The attribute is `DataFrame` capital `F`.

Comment: after correcting dataframe its showing value error

Comment: Correct. You can't have columns of unequal length. `Name` and `Roll.No.` have 3 rows, but `marks` has 4 rows.